# create a vector with sequences of arbitrary length

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I want to create a vector of length `n` which will contain sequences of arbitrary length

I made a code that does this, but it seems unreliable and a little ridiculous to me.

```
n <- 300
vals <- c(-1,0,1)
seq_range <- 3:20

make_seq <- function() sample(vals,size=1) |> rep(sample(seq_range,1))
my_seq <- lapply(1:50,\(x) make_seq())  |> unlist() |> tail(n = n)
```

...

```
my_seq
  [1]  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [35]  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 [69]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[103] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[137]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
[171]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1
[205] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
[239]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[273]  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I create a list and then cut it to size `n`, I don't like it...
Is there a way or a ready-made function that can replace my code and make it better?

==============================================================

1. sequences inside the vector `my_seq` have arbitrary length
2. vector `my_seq` has a length `n`
3. I want to set the length range of sequences in a vector  for example, as in my code `rep(sample(3:20,1))` What does it mean that the length of any sequence is from `3` to `20`
4. I want to indicate the elements of sequences, it can be either -1,0,1 or something else with a different set and number of elements, for example 0,1 or 1,5,10,20.
   But these will always be `int` values

Comment: I think you may need to be more specific - what do you mean make sequences of arbitrary length?  You you want to be able to specify the lengths of sequences or do you want it randomised? Do you need to be able to specify the sequence items or will it always be `-1, 0, 1`?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question

Comment: It might be somewhat easier to gasp with just vectors (i,e.`vlen <- ceiling(n/min(seq_range)); rep(x = sample(vals, vlen, replace = TRUE), times = sample(seq_range, vlen, replace = TRUE))[1:n]`),  but what makes your think your aproach is unreliable?

Comment: I like your answer.
My approach is not reliable because...lapply(1:50....
this 1:50 size is only suitable for n <- 300 but will not fit for n <- 5000

Comment: @margusl - you can get runs longer than the max of seq_range because the same value can be sampled consecutively.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento , indeed, excellent point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you intending to do?

```r
n <- 300
vals <- c(-1, 0, 1)
seq_range <- 3:20

seqs <- sample(seq_range, n %/% min(seq_range), replace = TRUE)
M <- min(which(cumsum(seqs) >= n))
v <- sample(vals, M, replace = TRUE)
rep(v, seqs[1:M])[1:n]
```

Comment: Same problem as mentioned by @Ritchie